# Create a livestream by XSplit Encoder (RTMP Server)

Tags: c#, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

I'm making a program for do a livestream of the XSplit Encoder (RTMP Server). I need to have a site to watch that stream, and this program, the player need to have a button to the spectator can choose your video quality, and the stream have to be fluid and have a good quality. Can someone explain this or send me a link to do that? Please
(C#)

Comment: Why did you tag this with http-live-streaming?

Comment: Because I was need to tag this with "livestream", but I don't have sufficient reputation to tag with this, and http-live-streaming is the most similar

Answer (score 0):

This is a VERY large undertaking. And an impossible question to answer unless you narrow the scope. You need a ingest server that takes in RTMP, You need a machine with enough CPU power to do all the transcodes. You need site to playback on. You also need enough bandwidth (CDN) for all your viewers. How many viewers do you need to support? What platforms do you want to play back on? iOS? then you need HLS. Web? then you need RTMP. Or you can use DASH if your ok with limiting it to modern browsers. Do you want it to play in firefox? Then it MUST be flash, because firefox does not have native support for the h.264 codec. But flash wont play in iOS. You can use JWPlaver premium, that will play HLS in flash. Actually is h.264 the codec you intend to use? Have you looked into services such as Zencoder live transcoding? Or Wowza with the transcoding module? Amazon offers preconfigured wowza instances. What is your budget for this project? Why not just use twitch?

Edit: You can probably string something together using ffmpeg:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide

Comment: Well, there's a way to integrate a youtube livestream in my form? But the strem goes on air everyday, and it must be easy to start the livestream to all people whose have the program, without much configuration... there's a way? I need to stream to all browsers, maybe I create an Android and iOS app...